# Missing a property name before the colon (':') in the "(property)" :(value)" declaration. css global variable

Tags: css, asp.net

I want to create a global variable in css I have looked online how to do it and every website says to declare a css variable you most do the following
:root{
  --variableName:property;
} according to https://medium.freecodecamp.org/everything-you-need-to-know-about-css-variables-c74d922ea855 
However in visual studio I get the following error :Missing a property name before the colon (':') in the "(property)" :(value)" declaration?

Here is my code.

```
:root{
 --main-color:#4d4e53;
 --main-bg: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 --logo-border-color: rebeccapurple;

  --header-height: 68px;
  --content-padding: 10px 20px;

 --base-line-height: 1.428571429;
 --transition-duration: .35s;
 --external-link: "external link";
 --margin-top: calc(2vh + 20px);

  --foo: if(x > 5) this.width = 10;
}
```

Why does visual studio say Missing a property name before the colon (':') in the "(property)" :(value)" declaration?

Comment: They are all invalid.Even if I remove the last one I still get the same error for all the rest.

Comment: so VS is not configured to support custom properties probably

Comment: How would I configure it to support custom properties?

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach I don't have extensive experience with VS but this might be a good source to start with: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/how-to-add-a-custom-property?view=vs-2017

Comment: And when I try to call the variable for exemple   background-color: var(--main-color); I get the following error Validation (CSS 3.0) "var(--main-color)" is not a valid value for the background-color" property.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach You can use custom properties in css on vs. Have you defined the style attributes at the top of your css file?

Comment: @TemaniAfif VS 2015 onwards support custom properties

Comment: @JamesS how do I defined the style attributes at the top of my css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your custom properties at the top of your css such as this:

```
Style Attribute{
    --PrimaryColour : #71b220;
    --SecondaryColour: #FFFFFF;
    --TertiaryColour: #337ab7;
}
```

You can then create classes and use them in your program such as this:

`.PrimaryColour{
    color:var(--PrimaryColour);
}`

Comment: It still gives me the same errors Missing a property name before the colon (':') in the "(property)" :(value)" and Validation (CSS 3.0) "var(--PrimaryColour)" is not a valid value for the background-color" property.

Comment: Yes the error is in visual studio 2015 and when I try to run the code it ignores my css when I try to create global variables and use them.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach If you are running your code using Google Chrome, are you able to go into your developer tools and see the variables? Using Visual Studio 2015 I don't get an error, however the custom property is underlined with a green line and a line saying the error you have. The custom property still works though.

Comment: Yes, I can see it in chrome. And you are right in visual studio the property is underlined with a green line how to I fix it.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach While you have the dev tools open, right click on the page refresh icon and do a hard refresh. Also, as I beleive this was the first VS to implement custom properties in the css file it can be quite tempermental, you may have to make sure there are no other errors on the page otherwise they won't show.

Comment: The code is still underlined in green even when i refresh the page with the dev tools open.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach That's fine. With VS 2015 that will always be the case, the colours however, if configured correctly should show. What are you seeing when you go to the screen where you expect to see your custom properties applied? Are they being over-ruled by another class?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I will soon upgrade to visual studio 2017 anyways.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach If this answer helped please feel free to upvote the answer to aid others.